# Calculating a power: how to test for values that exceed INT_MAX or INT_MIN?

Tags: c, recursion, integer-overflow

I am trying to implement a simple program to recursively calculate the power of numbers. The code tests for values that exceed either `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN` and should assign `power = -1`. However, even after certain number of recursive calls, when result variable has exceeded the maximum value, it is not printing the error message like I had hoped for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

void power(int x, int n, int* result);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x, n, result = 1;
    x = 10;
    n = 20;

    if (n < INT_MIN || x < INT_MIN)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Argument(s) out of range\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (n > INT_MAX || x > INT_MAX)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Argument(s) out of range\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (x != 0)
    {
        power(x, n, &result);
        if (result == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Result is out of range\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("%d to the power %d = %d\n", x, n, result);
    return 0;
}



void power(int x, int n, int *result)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (*result > INT_MAX)
    {
        *result = -1;
        return;
    }

    if (*result < INT_MAX)
    {
        *result = (*result) * x;
        power(x, n - 1, result);
    }       
}
```

Comment: How do you think an `int` can be out of `int`s bounds? Think!

Comment: Are you sure a recursive solution is superior to a simple loop?

Answer (score 2):

(your next-to-last line of code:) When `*result = (*result) * x;` returns more than INT_MAX, it fails, maybe the *result will contain the remainder of the result % INT_MAX, but maybe something wild - You never get a chance to test it in the next iteration for being larger.

if you want to test that the result still is good, you need to check if the product is out of range *before* actually calculating it, for example use: `if (*result < INT_MAX/x)`. If that is true, you *can* still multiply once more.

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: ?? It explains why it fails. I am at a loss what you could mean.

Comment: "and *result will only contain the remainder of the result % INT_MAX" nope, what happens is undefined.

Comment: Should be `if (*result <= INT_MAX/x)`.  `result % INT_MAX` would be a strange manifestation of undefined behavior (`int` overflow) , perhaps you meant  the math equivalent of `result % (INT_MAX + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

It is too late to check for overflow after you have done the multiplication, but you can test before you do it.

```
*result = (*result) * x;
```

Could be done like this

```
if(INT_MAX / x < *result) {
    *result = -1;
}
else {
    *result *= x;
}
```

Your code must be for positive numbers, since you use `-1` to signify overflow (itself a power of `-1`). In that case, use `unsigned int` or even a bigger type tot get more range.

**EDIT**:

I have altered your program a bit, to return the result instead of using a pointer argument. It works for positive numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int x, int n)
// calculate x power n
{
    int res;
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    res = power(x, n-1);             // recurse
    if(INT_MAX / res < x) {          // check for overflow
        return -1;
    }
    return x * res;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, n;
    n = 10;
    for(i=0; i<11; i++) {
        printf("%d power %d = %d\n", n, i, power(n, i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
10 power 0 = 1
10 power 1 = 10
10 power 2 = 100
10 power 3 = 1000
10 power 4 = 10000
10 power 5 = 100000
10 power 6 = 1000000
10 power 7 = 10000000
10 power 8 = 100000000
10 power 9 = 1000000000
10 power 10 = -1
```

Comment: Missing cases: `n-1` could overflow with `n` negative.  (Stack overflow more likely).  Stack overflow likely with `x == 1` and large `n`.  Division by 0 with `power(0, two_or_more)`

Comment: @chux, good catches, the `n` negative I already mentioned. I did not want to depart too far from OP's way: I would use have worked off the bits of the power - both of us have previously answered like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can only prevent getting above INT_MAX, since actually getting above will cause overflows. Unless you can capture overflows (C offers nothing, sadly) you will have to PREVENT them.

The other answer to divide before multiplying actually allows you to do this kind of prevention.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 **Improve algorithm**
OP's current method takes `n` iterations/recursions.  Rather than `n` calls with `power(x, n-1);`, use `log2(n)` calls and halve `n` each time,

Recursion not really needed.  A simple loop will do.

Step 2: **Test multiplication**
Before multiplication, test for potential overflow.  [Ref](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/93699/29485)

```
int is_undefined_mult1(int a, int b) {
  if (a > 0) {
    if (b > 0) {
      return a > INT_MAX / b;       // a positive, b positive
    }
    return b < INT_MIN / a;         // a positive, b not positive
  }
  if (b > 0) {
    return a < INT_MIN / b;         // a not positive, b positive
  }
  return a != 0 && b < INT_MAX / a; // a not positive, b not positive
}
```

Step 3 **Test for peculiar inputs**
Example: raising to a negative power.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

// return true on overflow
bool power(int x, int y, int *zp) {
  // Handle negative exponent cases
  if (y < 0) {
    switch (x) {
      case 1:
        *zp = 1;
        return false;
      case -1:
        *zp = y % 2 ? -1 : 1;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  int z = 1;
  int base = x;
  for (;;) {
    if (y % 2) {
      if (is_undefined_mult1(z, base)) return true;
      z *= base;
    }
    y /= 2;
    if (y == 0) break;
    if (is_undefined_mult1(base, base)) return true;
    base *= base;
  }
  *zp = z;
  return false;
}
```